# Prove of the following equation: $\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{A^{m-k}}{(m-k)!} \cdot \frac{B^k}{k!} = \frac{(A+B)^m}{m!}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

While studying Analysis I encoutered the following equation:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{A^{m-k}}{(m-k)!} \cdot \frac{B^k}{k!} = \frac{(A+B)^m}{m!}$$

I was asked to prove it and the start went pretty well, but now I've been stuck for hours and don't see my mistake. Can someone help?

Let $A,B \in \Bbb C^{nxn}$ be commutative matrices.

Proof by induction:

Ind.-Start: Let $m=1$, so:
$\sum_{k=0}^1 \frac{A^{1-k}}{(1-k)!} \cdot \frac{B^k}{k!} =\frac{A^1}{(1)!} \cdot \frac{B^0}{0!} + \frac{A^0}{(0)!} \cdot \frac{B^1}{1!} = A+B =\frac{(A+B)^1}{1!} \\\square$

Ind.-Step:
$m \to m+1$

$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} \frac{A^{m+1-k}}{(m+1-k)!} \cdot \frac{B^k}{k!} &= \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{A^{m-k}}{(m-k)!} \cdot \frac{B^k}{k!} + \frac{A^{m+1-m-1}}{(m+1-m-1)!}\cdot \frac{B^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}\\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{A^{m-k}}{(m-k)!} \cdot \frac{B^k}{k!} + \frac{B^{m+1}}{(m+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(A+B)^m}{m!} + \frac{B^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}
\end{align*}$

Comment: Just use the binomial theorem

Comment: Isn't there a problem in your induction step? Where is your $m+1$ in the sum after the first equality?

Comment: In the inductive step, when the sum is decomposed, the sum still has $A^{m+1-k}$ and $(m+1-k)!$

Comment: But doesn't it "go away" by taking $m+1$ out of the sum?

Comment: When taking out $m+1$, the only thing changed are the summation bounds, not the summand themselves.

Comment: Yeah you're totally right. Thank you very much! I'll try it out but it seems as if that solves all my problems!